# Iteration issues with nested for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, nested

I am having a problem looping through an array of point objects, comparing each object to the other objects, and pushing it to a subarray. The main problem is with the iteration using the for loop. First, I have a set of points:

```
 var points = [
   { id: 1, x: 0.0, y: 0.0 },
   { id: 2, x: 10.1, y: -10.1 },
   { id: 3, x: -12.2, y: 12.2 },
   { id: 4, x: 38.3, y: 38.3 },
   { id: 5, x: 79.0, y: 179.0 }
 ];
```

I then want to compare each point to ALL the other points. Apparently, my method is just comparing the `i` to the `j` that's next in line in the array. What I want is a subarray for each point object that has the objects id, the id of the point object it's being compared to, and the distance between those 2 points. Ex output: `[{1, 2, 12.74423}, {1, 2, 10.76233), {1, 3, 43.23323}, {1, 4, 23.45645}, {1, 5, 127.43432}];` Here is my code, and below that is the output I get in my console. What am I doing wrong here? Note: I put in some random `console.logs` to see what was going on.

```
   var pointPairs = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i = i + 1) {
     var p1 = points[i];
     for (let j = i + 1; j < points.length; j = j + 1) {
       var p2 = points[j];
       var distance = Math.sqrt((p1.x - p2.x) ** 2 + (p1.y - p2.y) ** 2);
       pointPairs.push({ p1: p1.id, p2: p2.id, distance });
       console.log(pointPairs);
     };

   };
```

Results:

```
0:{p1: 1, p2: 2, distance: 14.28355697996826}
1:{p1: 1, p2: 3, distance: 17.253405460951758}
2:{p1: 1, p2: 4, distance: 54.16437943888954}
3:{p1: 1, p2: 5, distance: 195.65786465153911}
4:{p1: 2, p2: 3, distance: 31.536962440920014}
5:{p1: 2, p2: 4, distance: 56.01606912306503}
6:{p1: 2, p2: 5, distance: 201.26107422946941}
7:{p1: 3, p2: 4, distance: 56.84593213238745}
8:{p1: 3, p2: 5, distance: 190.10439237429526}
9:{p1: 4, p2: 5, distance: 146.46835835770128}
```

Comment: Start `j` at 0, just like `i`, and only add a distance when `i !== j`

Comment: This isn't recursive, it's just two nested loops.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: @gwydion93 can you explain how the original output you posted does not include the distance between every distinct pair of points? Can you give one of the pairs that is missing, in other words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointy is right about needing to start at zero in your second loop.

If you just need to iterate through a list, I recommend avoiding for-loops. They are verbose and error-prone, compared to the built-in array iteration method (`Array.forEach`). Here is your code, converted to use `Array.forEach`. I think you'll agree that it's much simpler.

```js
var points = [
   { id: 1, x: 0.0, y: 0.0 },
   { id: 2, x: 10.1, y: -10.1 },
   { id: 3, x: -12.2, y: 12.2 },
   { id: 4, x: 38.3, y: 38.3 },
   { id: 5, x: 79.0, y: 179.0 }
]
var pointPairs = [];
points.forEach((p1, i) => {
    points.forEach((p2, j) => {
        var distance = Math.sqrt((p1.x - p2.x) ** 2 + (p1.y - p2.y) ** 2);
        pointPairs.push({ p1: p1.id, p2: p2.id, distance });
        console.log(pointPairs);
    })
})
```

Comment: While this is not 100% accurate, using a combo of @Pointy 's suggestion and this, I was able to get a solution that worked. Basically, I added an `if` statement based on `i !== j` before running my `distance` calculations and pushing to the subArray.

Answer (score 0):

It does appear that your algorithm is working, if the goal is to make a single comparison between any two points - i.e. if `p1` and `p2` are considered unordered - a combination, not a permutation.

However, if you wish that `p1` and `p2` contain every possible permutation, not just combination, then start `j` at `0` and skip the iteration where `i===j`:

```
   var pointPairs = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i = i + 1) {
     var p1 = points[i];
     innerLoop: for (let j = 0; j < points.length; j = j + 1) {
       if (j===i) continue innerLoop;
       var p2 = points[j];
       var distance = Math.sqrt((p1.x - p2.x) ** 2 + (p1.y - p2.y) ** 2);
       pointPairs.push({ p1: p1.id, p2: p2.id, distance });
       console.log(pointPairs);
     };

   };
```

(The  `innerLoop` [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) is not strictly needed, but helps clarify the code when you have nested loops)

Comment: I think the fact that this technique requires a label to read easily means it's the wrong approach. I've never seen a label in the wild, and it's for good reason.

Comment: Yeah, I would recommend not using nested loops in general, because they get confusing fast. @posit-labs gives a [nicer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51050800/8031815). IMHO, I think the label clarifies here, but other people may be more confused by it. The label is optional, but for me I sleep better by explicitly specifying which loop is being skipped, and not relying on remembering that implicitly it's the inner loop.